# Multiple import under same namespace typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, import, leaflet, ionic3

I know it is going to be a silly question, but I've looked around and found nothing which helped me understand.

I have an ionic project, on which I imported [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com)
Now everything works fine, I imported it using this code:

```
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
```

Now I wanted to add [leaftlet.easyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) to my project.

In my mind this library should extend the leaflet one, right?

```
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import leaflet from 'leaflet-easybutton';
```

This approach give a problem with the namespace, of course.

Now what I want to achieve is to use leaflet by extending his methods to include the one provided by the easybutton library.

In order to be able to do something like:

```
leaflet.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map){
     helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
}).addTo( YOUR_LEAFLET_MAP );
```

So the question is, how do I import the second library in typescript in order to be able to use it as the above example showed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Leaflet.EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) plugin only performs the side effect of attaching some new methods (`easyButton`…) and classes (`Control.EasyButton`…) to the `L` Leaflet global namespace.

Therefore you should just need to import it for side effect:

```ts
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-easybutton';

L.easyButton( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me forever for some simple sintax.

Answer (score 1):

I've encounted a similar problem trying to import two different Keyboard plugins. A solution is to name one of the plugins like this:

```
// imports
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import * as easyButton from 'leaflet-easybutton';


// usage
leaflet //first plugin
easyButton.leaflet //second plugin
```

Comment: I tried, but with you correction I get an error which is:
`Property 'leaflet' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/zeno/ticaccio/node_modules/leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button"'.`

Trying to run the following code: 
`    lfEasyButton.leaflet.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map){console.log("cicked");}).addTo(this.map);`

Comment: Shouldn't it be easyButton.leaflet.easyButton instead of EasyButton.leaflet.easyButton?

Comment: Changed.
Property 'leaflet' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/zeno/ticaccio/node_modules/leaflet-easyButton/src/easy-button"'.

Still it seems that easyButton has no leaflet, thus not extending>

Right now I'm trying to change how the module are imported but I'm having no luck